# Compute level set of functions

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis

I've just learnt the notion of "level set in topology", I'm looking forward to compute the level set of 3 functions for c=0, 1 , -1 and 2, could you tell me if I'm right ?

$1)f(x,y)=\sqrt{(x^2+y^2)}$

So for $c=0$ we have $y=-x$

for $c=1$ we have $y=\sqrt{1-x^2}$

for $c=-1$ we have $y=\sqrt{-1-x^2}$

for $c=2$ we have $y=\sqrt{4-x^2}$$

$2)f(x,y)=\frac{y}{x}$

So for $c=0$ we have $y=0$

for $c=1$ we have $y=x$

for $c=-1$ we have $y=-x$

for $c=2$ we have $y=2x$

$3)f(x,y)=ax+by+c$

So for $c=0$ we have $y=\frac{-ax-c}{b}$

for $c=1$ we have $y=\frac{1-ax-c}{b}$

for $c=-1$ we have $y=\frac{-1-ax-c}{b}$

for $c=2$ we have $y=\frac{2-ax-c}{b}$

Thank you very much

Comment: Hint; $x^2+y^2=0 $  iff $x=y=0$, and $\sqrt{-1-x^2}$ is not real. The other answers seem correct.

Comment: Part 1), $c = -1$, the level set is empty, unless you are working in the complex field $\mathbb{C}$, because $\sqrt{-1-x^2}=y$ has no real solutions.